# Complex Query LINQ Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to extract data in a single query.
Since it involves many tables, I am sort of stuck at the grouping part.

I do not have enough reputation to post image of my table design.
So, I am giving PK,FK

```
 Sector (SectorId)
 Device (DeviceId:PK, CategoryId:FK)
 Ratio (SectorId,DeviceId)
 Use (UseId)
 DeviceUse (SectorId,DeviceId,UseId)
 Family (FamilyId)
 Category (CategoryId)
 Level (LevelId)
 Age(AgeId)
 Consu (SectorId,DeviceId,LevelId)
 DistributionOne (SectorId,DeviceId,LevelId)
 DistributionTwo (SectorId,DeviceId,LevelId, AgeId)
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

Given a `sectorId`, retrieve all related information from all the tables given.

The result would be:

all `Devices`

grouped by `Family`

grouped by `Category`

and all  `Ratios` (for given `sectorId` and `deviceId`)

and all  `DeviceUses` (for related `sectorId` and `deviceId`) and the related `Use` for the `deviceId`

and all  `Consu` (for related `deviceId`, `levelId`, `ageId`) and the related `Age` and `Level`

and all  `DistributionOne` (for related `deviceId`, `levelId`, `sectorId`) and the related `Level`

and all  `DistributionTwo` (for related `deviceId`, `levelId`, `sectorId`, `ageId`) and the related `Age` and `Level`

So far I got a method as below.

```
public IEnumerable<UserConfig> GetDeviceType(int sectorId)
    {
        var t = repo.GetAll().AsQueryable()                
            .Select(
            c => new UserConfig
            {
                Device = new Device { Name = c.Name, Id = c.Id },
                DistributionOne = c.DistributionOne.Where(d => d.SectorId == sectorId && d.DeviceId == c.Id).ToList(),
                DistributionTwo = c.DistributionTwo.Where(d => d.SectorId == sectorId && d.DeviceId == c.Id).ToList(),
                Consu = c.Consu.Where(d=>d.DeviceId == c.Id).ToList(),
                Category = c.Category,
                Family = c.Category.Family,
                DeviceUse = c.DeviceUse.Where(d => d.SectorId == sectorId && d.DeviceId == c.Id).ToList(),
                Ratios = c.Ratios.Where(d => d.SectorId == sectorId && d.DeviceId == c.Id).ToList(),
                Use = c.DeviceUse.Where(d=>d.DeviceId==c.Id && d.SectorId==sectorId).Select(u=>u.Use).FirstOrDefault()
            });       

        var devices = t.ToList();
        return devices;
    }
```

where `repo` is a repository of `Device`

`GetAll` is the repository method to get the set of `Devices`.

My questions:

- Am i doing it the right way?
- If Yes, then how do I group the data to get a nested collection of

> Families
>   ->Categories
>   --->Devices
>   DistributionOne
>   DistributionTwo
>   ..etc

- If not, then what do I need to correct (my table design?, query?)

Comment: Is there actually a problem here or are you just looking for a critique on your code? If so, this question is off-topic and you should post at http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I would like to know how to do grouping to get the nested collection

Comment: Break it up to use some methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GroupBy` operator:

```
var t = repo.GetAll().AsQueryable()
.GroupBy(c => c.Category.Family.ID)
.Select(g => new {
    FamilyID = g.Key,
    DevicesByCategory = g.GroupBy(c => c.Category.ID)
        .Select(g2 => new {
            CategoryID = g2.Key,
            Devices = g2.Select(c => new UserConfigs {
                ....
        })
   })
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i am doing, projecting into viewmodels and using grouping